# Measure thickness of multiple layers using ultrasound

Tags: electromagnetism, acoustics, soft-question

I am trying to build an ultrasound thickness measurement device using either Arduino or raspberry pi (haven't decided on which yet), before i start i have a doubt and am hoping someone can clarify the doubt

Will ultrasound travel from a medium with higher speed to a medium with lower speed or is just one way i.e from lower speed to higher speed.

The place i am trying to implement this ultrasound machine is having layers where the speed of ultrasound will be faster on the outermost layer and then it will gradually decrease. can i use a ultrasound thickness measurement device to find the thickness of all the layers present?

Comment: As a hint, if you look at an ultrasound picture of a baby, if you can see a line where the ultrasound went into bone, out of bone, and you can see things on the other side, that is proof that it can traverse in both directions.  It may, however, be worth noting that ultrasound picks up impedance mismatches.  Gradual changes are much harder.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, yes. Anytime sound passes from one substance into a substance in which the speed of sound is different, some energy will be reflected and some refracted. But, the amount reflected is simply based on the ratio between the speeds of sound in those media. So it doesn't matter too much whether it's going from a faster medium to a slower medium or vice versa. However, if it crosses an interface between two mediums where the speed of sound is basically the same, hardly any energy will reflect, so you won't get an echo that can be detected by a transducer. If the difference is too great, then almost all the energy will be reflected and none of it will pass through to the next medium.